# LLVM pass converting integer to float

Tags: casting, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am writing an LLVM pass that needs to convert an integer type into various floating point types.  I am trying to use the UIToFp instruction to convert the integer value into a floating point value.  As a basic test case I am using code similar to

`Value* promotedRandom = Builder.CreateUIToFP(ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(M.getContext()), 4), Type::getFloatTy(M.getContext()));`

where Builder is an instance of IRBuilder for my function.  However for some reason this value is 0 instead of 4 after the conversion which I can confirm by printing the value.  Strangely if the type argument to CreateUIToFP is a double type instead of a float type the correct answer of 4 is printed instead.  In the documentation of UIToFP below I don't see any reason for this behavior occurring.  What is the cause of this problem and how should it be fixed.

*Convert an unsigned integer constant to the corresponding floating-point constant. TYPE must be a scalar or vector floating-point type. CST must be of scalar or vector integer type. Both CST and TYPE must be scalars, or vectors of the same number of elements.*

Additionally if i compile this code with clang

```
int main(){
    int test = 4;
    float test2 = (float)test;
    printf("%f\n", test2);
}
```

I get the following instructions

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca float, align 4
  store i32 4, i32* %1, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %4 = sitofp i32 %3 to float
  store float %4, float* %2, align 4
  %5 = load float, float* %2, align 4
  %6 = fpext float %5 to double
  %7 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), double %6)
  ret i32 0
}
```

which shows sitofp and integer to float conversion working correctly.  Even though im uitofp instead of sitofp, I have tried both and neither work.

Comment: casting an unsigned int to float sacrifices precision. I'm guessing that zero should be llvm's response to precision loss or undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem was that printf does not take a float as an argument.  When floats are passed to printf they are promoted to doubles.  When I took the float value and then promoted it to a double value the code worked correctly.